# PUT Request with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, http, put

I am trying to develop my own smart home app. For this I have to send a PUT request to my Raspberry.

I've already done it on my PC with this code:

```
HttpResponse<String> response1 = Unirest.put("http://192.168.1.151:80/api/09107DA986/lights/1/state")
      .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
      .body("{ \"on\": " + on + ",\r\n  \"bri\": " + bri + ",\r\n  \"hue\": " + hue + ",\r\n  \"sat\": " + sat + ",\r\n  \"transitiontime\": " + transitiontime + "\r\n}")
      .asString();
```

Now I also try it on my cell phone with Android Studio, but I can't get it.
I'm looking for a solution that is similar to my computer code.

Comment: please rephrase your question. It is not clear what exactly you are asking

Comment: did you used Gradle with Eclipse? you probably need to install all the dependencies

Comment: Thanks @LenaBru! I have rewritten it!

Comment: Do you have a stack trace or something?

Comment: _"I'm looking for a solution that is similar to my computer code."_ How about using a port of Unirest for Android: [https://github.com/zeeshanejaz/unirest-android](https://github.com/zeeshanejaz/unirest-android)

Comment: You could checkout https://square.github.io/retrofit/ and OkHttp, hide all the complexit crud for you